# Ubuntu 14.04 | Docker: security implications in run NginX in a container

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, docker

I was surfing around Docker Hub to find the NginX built-in image and i noticed the example commands to run NginX as web server in a container.

I wonder if this way, suggested on Docker Hub, to load the conf file

```
docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx
```

has security implications. Thinking at the worst case that may happen (get hacked), the attacker could be able to write into a shared folder (the docker volume). The same question goes around my mind about PHP/FPM..  should i map the folder of the php-fpm .config files? or should i rather keep all configs isolated inside the container?

One more thing (i am at the first approaches to docker): having my PHP application/website hosted in a container, where should i have to place the php files? in this case, i'd place the files into, to say, /www/myapp on the "main" file system, then mapping that folder to /www/html/myapp into the container..

thank you for your comments/suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

In the command you give, the nginx.conf file is the only mount from the host system, and it's mounted read-only.  That's relatively safe.

Mounting volumes from other containers is also pretty safe.

The one to watch is where you have read-write mounts of host folders.  In that case, a process running as root in the container can create things like suid files on the host.  Even so, they need elevated privileges inside the container, and also to be able to run something outside the container to make use of the suid executable they've created.

Using the nginx container for static content doesn't give much of an attack surface, so it's probably not going to be a problem that nginx runs as root, and with only static content, there's no need for any writeable volumes to be mounted on that container.

`php-fpm` is a whole different story.  run it as a non-root user, and don't do anything silly like mounting a writeable volume that contains scripts that the root user on the host might run.